# GLM.fit() in Matlab vs. Python Statsmodels: why the different results?

Tags: matlab, numpy, glm, statsmodels

**In what ways is Matlab's `glmfit` implemented differently than Python statsmodels' `GLM.fit()`?**

Here is a comparison of their results on my dataset: 
[image]
This represents graph 209 weights, generated from running GLM fit on:

`V`: (100000, 209) predictor variable (design matrix)

`y`: (100000,1) response variable

Sum of squared errors: 18.140615678

### A Specific Example

Why are these different? First, here's a specific example in Matlab:

```
yin = horzcat(y,ones(size(y)));
[weights_mat, d0, st0]=glmfit(V, yin,'binomial','probit','off',[],[],'off');
```

Let's try the equivalent in Python:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

## set up GLM
y = np.concatenate((y, np.ones( [len(y),1] )), axis=1)
sm_probit_Link = sm.genmod.families.links.probit
glm_binom = sm.GLM(sm.add_constant(y), sm.add_constant(V_design_matrix), family=sm.families.Binomial(link=sm_probit_Link))
     # statsmodels.GLM format: glm_binom = sm.GLM(data.endog, data.exog, family)

## Run GLM fit
glm_result = glm_binom.fit()
weights_py = glm_result.params 

## Compare the difference
weights_mat_import = Matpy.get_output('w_output.mat', 'weights_mat') # imports matlab variables
print SSE(weights_mat_import, weights_python)
```

### Let's Check The Docs

glmfit in Matlab:

`[b,dev,stats] = glmfit(X,y,distr)`

GLM.fit() setup in Python ([documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.fit.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.fit) ) :

`glm_model = sm.GLM(endog, exog, family=None, offset=None, exposure=None, missing='none', **kwargs)`

`glm_model.fit(start_params=None, maxiter=100, method='IRLS', tol=1e-08, scale=None, cov_type='nonrobust', cov_kwds=None, use_t=None, **kwargs)`

**How might we get Matlab `glmfit` results with Statsmodels?**

Thank you!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the tools involved, but fitting usually needs a starting value. This is explicitly noted in the documentatin of the `statsmodels` version, and I suspect that the starting values are different between the two implementations. Unfortunately MATLAB doesn't even mention anything along these lines, so getting the exact same might be difficult. Do you really need the exact same result? If the goodness-of-fit is the same for both results, they could be equally good fits.